# How to copy resources from other module to specific location ? (maven)

Tags: maven-2, maven

I have a maven-managed project with some modules.
One module contains some native codes inside "src/main/resources/native" directory.
Second module packages all related modules to a WAR file.

Here comes the question : How to copy the "native/" directory (and its sub-directories) in first module to WEB-INF/native directory in the second module ?

I found a [copy resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) plugin , but it seems not what I want. (It copies directory inside the same module , but I want cross-module copy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is doable with [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) (that I would bind on the `prepare-package` phase) and the appropriate `excludes/includes` . See the [Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) example.

Comment: Thank you !
And ... I also found the recursive dir should be written :
"<includes>native/**\/*.*</includes>" ... too cumbersome ...

Answer (score 4):

The goal of modules in maven is to spearate them from each other. I am afraid there will be no satisfactory solution inside maven as this goes against the grain.

A solution could be to create a war archive with your resources and depend on that to build your final war.

I use for a project for example the camel-web resources by adding a dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-web</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The war resources are merged with my web resources.